# How to calculate difference of two column into third column at runtime

Tags: html, jsp

I have created a web application which fetch data from RTC tool.
So In that web application I have to calculate difference at runtime(for third column) basis on two column values.
First column value will be taken from RTC tool programmatically and for second column user will enter value in text boxes and for third column it will calculate difference automatically.
Let me know if we can calculate difference for this third column automatically and how?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without rendered HTML. If your columns are in a table, you can do

```js
const makeNum = str => isNaN(str) || str.trim() === ""? 0:+str;

document.getElementById("table").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("userInput")) { // <input class="userInput"
    const parent = tgt.closest("tr");
    const rtc = makeNum(parent.querySelector(".rtc").textContent); // <td class="rtc>value</td>
    const val = makeNum(tgt.value);
    parent.querySelector(".diff").textContent = rtc - val; // <td class="diff"></td>
  }
})
```

```html
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody id="table">
    <tr>
      <td class="rtc">1000</td>
      <td><input class="userInput"></td>
      <td class="diff"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rtc">2000</td>
      <td><input class="userInput"></td>
      <td class="diff"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rtc">3000</td>
      <td><input class="userInput"></td>
      <td class="diff"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rtc">4000</td>
      <td><input class="userInput"></td>
      <td class="diff"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rtc">5000</td>
      <td><input class="userInput"></td>
      <td class="diff"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery in you project they you can also try this:

Check the working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jahanzaibmuneer/hLcbvrte/)

JS:

```
$('.user-input').on('input', function() {
    var static_val = $(this).parent().prev().text();
    var user_val = $(this).val();
  var diff = parseInt(static_val) - parseInt(user_val);
  if(!isNaN(diff)){
    $(this).parent().next().text(diff);
  }else{
    $(this).parent().next().text('');
  }
});
```